# Alert Dialog jump to other activity

Tags: android

I had 2 button in Alert Dialog , I want to make it like if "EXIT" clicked , it will jump to MainActivity , when "Restrat" clicked it will jump to B_Activity
Thanks

```
alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE,"Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                }

            });
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Restart", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to make it like if "EXIT" clicked , it will jump to MainActivity

I guess you are on `MainActivity` when you open the dialog so, with a simple `dialog.dismiss();` it will retour you to the `MainActivity` if not you'll have to make an `intent` as follows

```
alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE,"Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      dialog.dismiss(); //if you are on `MainActivity`
      Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class); //if under this dialog you do not have your MainActivity
      getContext().startActivity(i);
  }
});
```

> when "Restrat" clicked it will jump to B_Activity

You have to make an `Intent` as follows

```
alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Restart", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
     Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), B_Activity.class)
     getContext().startActivity(i);
  }
```

*NOTE : After ask a question just read some basics about Android I'll explain a little bit the code.*

**Why use [`dialog.dismiss();`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#dismiss())?**

> Dismiss this dialog, removing it from the screen.

**Why use [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/Intent.html)?**

> An intent is an abstract description of an operation to be performed. It can be used with startActivity to launch an Activity, broadcastIntent to send it to any interested BroadcastReceiver components, and startService(Intent) or bindService(Intent, ServiceConnection, int) to communicate with a background Service.

**What's this [`getContext()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#getContext%28%29)?**

> Retrieve the Context this Dialog is running in and returns the Context used by the Dialog.

Hope this answer helped to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Intent to start an Activity,like that :

```
Intent i = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, TargetActivity.class); 
startActivity(i);
```

And write this code in the onClick method.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily swith your activities with the following code:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

But please take a time and read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)